# Is this html code OK for auto submitting (if there is a separate page needs to be appeared after submission)

Tags: javascript, html

This is something which is very much basic but I think this is one of the few ways to create an auto submission using html.

`<meta charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="refresh" content="120;url=http://localhost/Quiz/grade.php">`

Is this okay if I need to get a new page after submission.... Than typing large java-script codes. (I'm creating a quiz page for a Website and i need to show the results after 2 minutes in a new page)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's one way to redirect page. It's fine to use it.

*Side note*

If you ever auto-include head content to every page, than this code will redirect every page (I think it's not what you want, so keep in mind that).

---

Typo in `<meta>`:

```
 <meta charset=UTF-8">
```

must be

```
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
```